# ¿Cómo crear un dataframe en R desde un Excel con varias hojas?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

Tengo un libro en Excel con 10 hojas, cada una con el nombre de un país. La primera fila de todas las hojas es igual. Lo que necesito es unirlas todas en un solo dataframe en R.
He estado usando la libreria "readxlsx", pero solo puedo leer una hoja a la vez, y aún no sé como unirlas todas...

Cualquier ayuda será muy aprecidad

Saludos!

Comment: como seria en caso contrario, cuando tengo los nombres en una columna y quiero que todos los registro con ese / esos nombres se guarden en una hoja de forma independiente. saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te recomiendo usar lo siguiente:

debes cargar estas librerías

```
library(openxlsx)
library(purrr)
```

Primero definir la ruta donde tienes el archivo:
ejemplo:

```
Ruta_archivo = "C:/Users/Documents/archivo.xlsx"
```

Lo segundo es extraer los nombres de las hojas de tu libro excel con la función

```
hojas = getSheetNames(Ruta_archivo)
```

Finalmente leer todas las hojas y juntarlas

```
lista_df = map(hojas,function(x){
read.xlsx(Ruta_archivo ,sheet = x)
})

df = do.call(rbind,lista_df)
```

Espero te sirva, ojo que en el paso final, te las juntara todas siempre y cuando tengan las mismas variables.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Muy sencilla tu solución y sí me sirvió

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvio, podrias marcar la respuesta como correcta porfavor :)